# Photo Picker with READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED permission on Android 14 still shows all media content

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-14

In the Android 14 release, there is a new permission:

- **READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED**: The **READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED** permission is granted, providing partial and temporary access to the user's photos and videos.

This new permission has a new dialog with the following options:

- **Select photos and videos**: New in Android 14. The user selects the specific photos and videos that they want to make available to your app.
- **Allow all**: The user grants full-library access to all photos and videos on the device.
- **Don't allow**: The user denies all access.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/partial-photo-video-access

- In the document there is a note mentioning:

> Note: If your app already uses the photo picker, you don't need to take any action to support this change. Otherwise, consider using the photo picker instead of adopting this change.

When I try to implement the photo picker and test myapp.

Step 1: Request permission: "**READ_MEDIA_IMAGES**", "**READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED**"

Step 2: I select "**Select photos and videos**"

Step 3: Select a few photos -> Allow

Result: The PhotoPicker still displays all media content on the device instead of only displaying media content that has been granted permission.

Am I misunderstanding or is there a problem with my code?

If I don't understand correctly, what is the actual behavior? What should I do with it?

Everyone please let me know. Thanks.

I implemented the photo picker in two cases and got the same results. Here is my code:

Case 1 uses Intent:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;
    Button takePictureButton;
    int RESULT_CODE = 0;
    int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.img);
        takePictureButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_take_picture);

        takePictureButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 34) {
                int result14 = this.checkSelfPermission(READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED);
                boolean hasReadMediaPermissionAndroid14 = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == result14;

                if (hasReadMediaPermissionAndroid14) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_PICK_IMAGES);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_CODE);
                } else {
                    requestPermissions(new String[] {READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED}, REQUEST_CODE);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (data != null) {
            imageView.setImageURI(data.getData());
        }
    }
}
```

Case 2 follows the instructions in the documentation [Photo picker](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    Button takePictureButton;
    int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    ActivityResultLauncher<PickVisualMediaRequest> pickMedia =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia(), uri -> {
                if (uri != null) {
                    imageView.setImageURI(uri);
                    Log.d("PhotoPicker", "Selected URI: " + uri);
                } else {
                    Log.d("PhotoPicker", "No media selected");
                }
            });
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.img);
        takePictureButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_take_picture);

        takePictureButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 34) {
                        int result14 = this.checkSelfPermission(READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED);
                        boolean hasReadMediaPermissionAndroid14 = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == result14;

                        if (hasReadMediaPermissionAndroid14) {
                            pickMedia.launch(new PickVisualMediaRequest.Builder()
                                    .setMediaType(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly.INSTANCE)
                                    .build());
                        } else {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{READ_MEDIA_IMAGES, READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED}, REQUEST_CODE);
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

- AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED" />
```

- activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
        android:src="@drawable/img"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_take_picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="take picture"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/img"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

- evidence: [evidence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEfIi.gif)

Comment: @blackapps I'm sorry. I have edited it. Please help me check it.

Comment: @blackapps I have edited it. Please help me check it

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

My five cents:

If your app requests READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and the user confirms then your app can use the classic File class to list files in for instance the DCIM/Camera directory and see all files of the default Camera app.

This is true for Android 14 too.

But if it directly goes for READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED and the user selects four files in DCIM/Camera then after that the File.listFiles() function will only list those four files.

In my experience the new permission has nothing to do with PickVisualMedia() or ACTION_GET_CONTENT or ACTION_PICK_IMAGES only with the classic File class.

Well my five cents. I find the documentation pretty obscure too and messed a long while with this.

Comment: The READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED permission is not related to PhotoPicker. So, I have to use the File.listFiles() function and create my own gallery picker to display those images, right?

Comment: Sorry i dont know if my conclusion is ok. Personally i see yet no use for READ_MEDIA_VUSUAL_USER_SELECTED. Starting with: how to get an uri list of the uris the user selected?